# Regex Word Boundary in Perl not yield expected results

Tags: regex, perl

So I'm having an issue with pulling data from a string between 2 keywords. I understand that in regex I'm suppose to use the \b boundary tags and I've written the following for a test example, however it seems to only match the whole string instead of just the portion I want.

For example, the string: "here are more string words START OF INFORMATION SECTION some other stuff"

I am gathering text between "START" and "SECTION".

So I'm expecting "START OF INFORMATION SECTION", I believe.

This is the following snippet I have written in Perl specifically, but it doesn't yield the results I expected.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# This is perl 5, version 22, subversion 1 (v5.22.1) built for cygwin-thread-multi
use POSIX;

my $text = "here are more string words START OF INFORMATION SECTION some other stuff";

print "Original String: $text\n";

# this should provide me with the specific text between my two boundary words
$text =~ /\bSTART\b(.*?)\bSECTION\b/;

print "New String: $text\n";
```

Comment: check:- http://ideone.com/ko44Ro

Comment: Thanks for the comment, does $text =~ <code here> does that not set the text variable to the output? I thought the =~ would do that.

Comment: No, it only matches your `string` with `regex` .So you have to use capturing groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is simply testing whether the regex pattern matches the string, returning a true or false value to indicate whether there was a match. You discard that indicator

*If there was a match* then the strings *captured* using parentheses in the regex pattern will be assigned to the capture variables `$1`, `$2` etc.

It's unclear what you need to do, but this program prints everything between `START` and `SECTION`: in this case `OF INFORMATION`

There's no need for `use POSIX`, but `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` are essential

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $text = "here are more string words START OF INFORMATION SECTION some other stuff";

print "Original String: $text\n";

if ( $text =~ /\bSTART\b(.*?)\bSECTION\b/ ) {
    my $section = $1;
    print "New String:      $section\n";
}
```

#### output

```
Original String: here are more string words START OF INFORMATION SECTION some other stuff
New String:       OF INFORMATION
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, okay I was under the impression that I could use =~ and that would set the text variable as the matched data. I didn't realize that it's only performing a check and that the data I require would be within the $1 capture variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this

```
$text =~ /\b(START\b(.*?)\bSECTION)\b/;
print "New String: $1\n";
```

**[IDEONE DEMO](http://ideone.com/ko44Ro)**

`$1` is the first captured group.

As suggested by **[borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin)**

```
if ( $text =~ /\b(START\b(.*?)\bSECTION)\b/ ) {
    my $tmp = $1;
    print "New String:      $tmp\n";
}
```

Comment: You should *never* use `$1` etc. without first checking whether the pattern match succeeded. Those variables retain the value from the most recent pattern match, which could be enything

Comment: @Borodin Thanks for telling.I am not used to `PERL`

Answer (score 0):

The match operator doesn't change the string it matches.

You can use either of the following to inspect the captured string:

```
if ( $text =~ /\bSTART\b(.*?)\bSECTION\b/ ) {
    my $section = $1;
    print "New String: $section\n";
}
```

or

```
if ( my ($section) = $text =~ /\bSTART\b(.*?)\bSECTION\b/ ) {
    print "New String: $section\n";
}
```